# Triggers suddenly disappearing from services

Tags: zabbix

We have been facing this problem for a while. Suddenly, some triggers are disappearing from (apparently) random services.

And when I say disappearing I don't mean that the triggers are been deleted, they just aren't in their respective services. Which means that the triggers still exists, but the services are "pointing" to nowhere.

Right now, we are using a script to check if all services without children have triggers, but eventually this script warn us about some services without it. Last night, the script warned us about 96 services wihout triggers! We checked the logs everywhere and couldn't figure out what caused this abrupt "disappearance".

Is this some bug or something related to Zabbix itself? Do you have any suggestions?

We're using Zabbix 3.2 and 3.4.

Comment: Are those LLD-generated triggers?

Comment: No. Straightforward triggers inside a couple of templates.

Comment: Can you make note of trigger IDs, and see whether any of the disconnecting triggers have the ID changed? Any API-accessing scripts that manage any related aspect (triggers, services...)? Any automatic functionality (network discovery, API scripts) that could result in template linkage changes?

Comment: Apparently the trigger IDs didn't change. I'm assuming this because after this problem we didn't see an increment of the greatest trigger ID (i.e, before and after the problem the gratest trigger ID still the same). Yes, we have an API script that continuosly check for new alarms in some specific services and shoot some actions in other third-party integrations. No, any automatic functionality that could result in template linkage changes (we only use get methods throughout these integrations). And just one more thing: we had this problem before the deploy of any API-accessing scripts. Thanks!

Comment: Doe the API-using scripts only read information, or do they update anything in Zabbix? Also note that Zabbix 3.2 and 3.4 are not supported anymore.

Comment: No, the scripts only read information (only 'get' methods are been used). Yes, we know about the absence of supporting in these versions. That's why we're assuming it should be some kind of bug...

Comment: It seems somewhat unlikely that such a serious bug would be unnoticed for both 3.2 and 3.4. How do you link triggers to services?

Comment: Associating a trigger inside the configuration panel of an IT service. The trigger is linked with a host, as usual, and are configurated in a couple of templates, depending on what we want to monitor.

Comment: So you go and manually add triggers to 96 services in the case you described in the question? But in any case, this would require some hands-on debugging and likely has ventured outside the scope of one question... I'd suggest to test with the latest version of 3.2/3.4 first, and upgrade to a supported version if the problem is still there.